# How to set app.js in ExtJS 5.1 for MVC?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

I am try to create a grid-panel through RESTful service. I have created all required files but somehow ExtJS does not trigger/run application. As i noticed through Chrome Dev-Tool's 'Network' tab all files are loading but it is not browser any of view! As well as I am using ext-all-debug to see what is going on but there isn't any error on console!

So i thought probably i am missing something about ExtJS 5.1.1's MVC application-architect for running the application.

Could you please examine basic folder structure and "app.js" below.

**Folder:**

```
root/
index.html
app.js

..app/
...model/
....Model.js

...store/
....Store.js

...view/
....Main.js
....Header.js
....orest/
.....List.js
.....Form.js
```

and here is the **app.js**:

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});


Ext.application({
    models: [
        'Model'
    ],
    stores: [
        'Store'
    ],
    views: [
        'Main'
    ],
    name: 'ORest',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('ORest.view.Main');
    }

});
```

**Edit 1**: 
Here is the Main.js, calls Header and Cards classes:

```
Ext.define('ORest.view.Main', {
        extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
        alias: 'widget.main',

        requires: ['ORest.view.Header', 'ORest.view.Cards'],
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    padding: 5,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'header',
        height: 80
    }, {
        xtype: 'thecards',
        flex: 1 
    }]
});
```

Header.js:

```
Ext.define('ORest.view.Header', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'theheader',
    //requires: ['Ext.toolbar.Toolbar'],
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                cls: 'logo',
                width: 300
            }, {
                //Search will come here!
            }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

and Cards.js:

```
Ext.define('ORest.view.Cards', {    
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'thecards',
    requires: ['Ext.layout.container.Card', 'ORest.view.orest.ManageOrest'],
    layout: 'card',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'themanageorest',
                itemId: 'manageOrestCard'
            }]      
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: i just ran an alert and console.log on app.js's 'launch' property, both of them working well!

Comment: Show us the code for the 'ORest.view.Main' class

Comment: @scebotari66 i have added 2 more classes which are calling by Main and keeps to call for 2-3 more classes. I have following a tutorial from 'Enterprise Application with ExtJS' book which is published by Packt

Comment: Don't ask me why, but the Viewport is not added to the body automatically if you use `Ext.create`. What you want to do is use the [`mainView`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.Application.html#cfg-mainView) configuration like this: `mainView:'ORest.view.Main',`.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for reply but it didn't bootstrap as well! but i figure out some mistake in List.js class. Seems like store config! I'll check out and write down the situation as soon as possible.

Comment: I have checked in a fiddle that the DOM <body> has subelements if you use mainView, but no subelements if you use Ext.create. Yes, it didn't show anything afterwards, but the elements are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is solution;

Application did not run on browser hence I thought there is a problem on application architect *-related with MVC pattern-* to **bootstrap**.

But i just figure out that error was not arise in app.js file **-bootstrapping in this sense-** and all about was Store definition (and i'll not go deeper to explain, will be prolixity).

So in conclusion; if anyone will create an MVC based ExtJS 5.1.1 application, may use this folder/file structure to bootstrap application...

Thanks a lot.